# React Native exit app while in the background mode

Tags: react-native

I have a media application where I want to implement auto sleep features in the background and foreground both mode. When a user set a specific time the app start to counting and fired the function when it's meet the time. Everything is working except the `BackHandler.exitApp();` code in background mode. How can I exit the app from the background mode?

Answer (score 1):

I just used https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-exit-app plugin and it's fixed this problem.